# Compiling executables with pyinstaller when using modules that contain data files

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I've made a package using this [tutorial](https://realpython.com/pypi-publish-python-package/#using-the-real-python-reader) and for the most part it works perfectly. The package is called [colordict](https://github.com/aleferna12/colordict) and it is available on Pypi already. That said, I have an issue compiling scripts that use colordict with pyinstaller. The issue comes from the fact that the package stores data in json files. It seems like the non-code (json) files are not recognized by pyinstaller... Is this normal? Can I do anything to make sure my json files are packed with pyinstaller?

Let's say I want to compile test.py into an executable:

```
#test.py
import colordict
c = ColorDict()
```

I would then use the following command in a windows shell:

```
pyinstaller test.py
```

When running the Executable, the following error would be raised:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\path_to_test\\dist\\main\\colordict\\palettes'
```

Obs: The files are installed with pip just fine, the problem really only comes when using pyinstaller.